# How to update an XML TextView from an Android fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I am trying to update the text of a fragment's `TextView` from a `FragmentActivity`. In the `else` statement I'm creating a `Fragment` first, and then I update the `TextView` with an `updateItemView()` method that belongs to the fragment, but all I'm getting is a
null pointer exception.

I can update the `TextView` from the `if` statement but why I can't I update the `TextView`
from the `else` statement?

This is the code of the `FragmentActivity`:

```
public void toDeatailsBtn(View view){

    ItemFragment listFragment = (ItemFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(R.id.large_layout_list_item_fragment);

    if(listFragment != null){
        //The "if" code is working.
        listFragment.updateItemView();
    }

    // I'm swaping fragments here. I already added firstFragment to the
    //fragment_container FrameLayout in other code.
    else{
        ItemFragment secondFragment = new ItemFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction =
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, secondFragment);

        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();

        //This is giving me the null pointer exception, even though
        //secondFragment has been created in theory.
        secondFragment.updateItemView();
    }
}
```

The `Fragment` containing the `updateItemView()` `Method`:

```
public class ItemFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_fragment, container, false);
    }

    public void updateItemView(){
        TextView name = (TextView) getActivity()
        .findViewById(R.id.list_item_fragment);
        name.setText("TEST");
    }
}
```

The `TextView`:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_fragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:freezesText="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Finally the `FrameLayout` I'm using to replace fragments:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainFragmentActivity" />
```

Error log:

```
01-06 00:59:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1610): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-06 00:59:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
01-06 00:59:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
01-06 00:59:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
01-06 00:59:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-06 00:59:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-06 00:59:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-06 00:59:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-06 00:59:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 00:59:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-06 00:59:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-06 00:59:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-06 00:59:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-06 00:59:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1610): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-06 00:59:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 00:59:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-06 00:59:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
01-06 00:59:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     ... 11 more
01-06 00:59:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1610): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-06 00:59:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at com.site.myapp.ItemFragment.updateItemView(ItemFragment.java:27)
01-06 00:59:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at com.site.myapp.MainFragmentActivity.toDetailsBtn(MainFragmentActivity.java:90)
01-06 00:59:08.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That Fragment transaction isn't done immediately when you call commit, so the `TextView` can't be found right away when you call `updateItemView()`. Try to use [`FragmentManager.executePendingTransaction()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions%28%29) to force the transaction to be made:

```
//...
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransaction();
secondFragment.updateItemView();
```

Comment: Just wondering why the transaction isn't done immediately after `commit()`.

Comment: @user1952398 That's how the `Fragment` system was designed, asynchronously. Also you could just probably call the `updateItemView` from one of the `Fragment`'s callbacks and not from outside as calling that method is more of an initialization process. I don't see why your question would get downvoted, it's well asked and you also provided the relevant code + stacktrace with the exception.

Answer (score 0):

In `myFragment` class write a static method:

```
public static myFragment newInstance(String txt) {
        myFragment myfragment = new myFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("TEXT", txt);
        myfragment.setArguments(args);

        return myfragment;
    }
```

after that in `OnCreate` method of `myFragment` class `inflate` the `textView tv` and

```
tv.setText(getArguments().getString("TEXT"));
```

In main `FragmentActivity` class do:

```
myFragment fragment = myFragment.newInstance(textToBeSent);
```

before `replace`,

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fr_dynamic, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```